# Filter on two fields in ElasticSearch when one of the fields is only present sometimes

Tags: elasticsearch

Let's say we are looking for shoes with a max price of $100.
The shoes has a 'price' field, but can also have a 'discounted_price' fields.

As an example:

```
{
    "_index": "shoes",
    "_type": "shoe",
    "_id": "1",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
        "price": 150,
        "discounted_price": 90
    }
}
{
    "_index": "shoes",
    "_type": "shoe",
    "_id": "2",
    "_score": 2,
    "_source": {
        "price": 100,
        "discounted_price": null
    }
}
```

How would you construct a query for a max price of $100, which would return both documents in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
POST /shoes/shoe/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "minimum_should_match": 1,
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "filter": [
              {
                "range": {
                  "discounted_price": {
                    "lte": 100
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "exists": {
                  "field": "discounted_price"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "filter": [
              {
                "range": {
                  "price": {
                    "lte": 100
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "missing": {
                  "field": "discounted_price"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

For ES versions older than 2.0 you can use the following query instead:

```
POST /shoes/shoe/_search
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "minimum_should_match": 1,
          "should": [
            {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "range": {
                      "discounted_price": {
                        "lte": 100
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "exists": {
                      "field": "discounted_price"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "range": {
                      "price": {
                        "lte": 100
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "missing": {
                      "field": "discounted_price"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: getting a 400 error too long to paste ... QueryParsingException[[shoes] No query registered for [missing]];

Comment: ... QueryParsingException[[shoes] bool query does not support [filter]];

Comment: What version of ES do you have?

Comment: `{
  "status" : 200,
  "name" : "Phastos",
  "cluster_name" : "473282926275:xxx",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "1.5.2",
    "build_hash" : "62ff9868b4c8a0c45860bebb259e21980778ab1c",
    "build_timestamp" : "2015-04-27T09:21:06Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "4.10.4"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}`

Comment: Ok, a quite outdated version :D I've updated my answer to make it work with 1.5.2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117607/discussion-between-2083-and-val).